# Keep keys with their values after values have been sorted in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm completely new to JavaScript; please feel free to correct me on my technical terminology.

I have a set of key value pairs that are being appended to a list. The list is displayed as a dropdown menu where the values of the keys are the displayed options and the keys are included in the HTML tag. My boss has asked me to alphabetically sort those displayed values.

So far, I have iterated through the object with a for...in loop and extracted each key's value into an array. I sorted the array and I can now append the values to the list alphabetically.

What's the best way to keep the keys linked to their respective values, so that when I append the values their appropriate keys can be added as well?

Thanks.

**SHORT VERSION: How do I match keys back to their values after copying all values into an array and alphabetically sorting it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without having a separate array. Just use a compare function (i.e., a comparator). For example:

```
var arr = [
    {k: "c", v: 3},
    {k: "b", v: 2},
    {k: "d", v: 4},
    {k: "a", v: 1},
    {k: "e", v: 5}
];

//sort by value
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.v - b.v;
});
```

This gives you:

```
[
   {
      "k": "a",
      "v": 1
   },
   {
      "k": "b",
      "v": 2
   },
   {
      "k": "c",
      "v": 3
   },
   {
      "k": "d",
      "v": 4
   },
   {
      "k": "e",
      "v": 5
   }
]
```

To sort based on string values, you can do:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.v.localeCompare(b.v);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't sort the values alone, sort through a 2D array -- an array of arrays.

so it will look something like

```
Key1 | Val1
-----------
Key2 | Val2
-----------
Key3 | Val3
```

Then you sort based on the values, but you move both.

When sorted, it might look like

```
Key3 | Val3
-----------
Key1 | Val1
-----------
Key2 | Val2
```

And then when you're referring to the first value, you do `array[0][1]` and for the key to that value you would do `array[0][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom sort function.

```
var ar = [ {key: 1, value: "One"}, {key: 2, value: "Two"}, {key: 3, value: "Three"} ];

var sortFunction = function(kv1, kv2) {
    return kv1.value.localeCompare(kv2.value);
};

ar.sort(sortFunction);
```